# flow layout panel

Tags: c#, sql

I have flow layout panel with SQL and I know how to load items from SQL to flow layout panel as Buttons, but now I need your help every button have click event So how can I control on event of every Button that I load it

```
items_Panles.Controls.Clear();
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-6HNIPQ5;Initial Catalog=Anass;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123");
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Table_Employee", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
for(int i=0;i<dt.Rows.Count;i++)
{
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Name = "btn" + dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
        btn.Text = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
        btn.Height = 80;
        btn.Width = 75;
        items_Panles.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

this code is fire when I click on the Individual button

Comment: Please be more clear. Do you need this code to applied to every button that its generated? Saying you have a flow layout panel with SQL is nonsense. You don'd load buttons using SQL. Please attempt to rewrite this question more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Stub out your click method, for example:

```
void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Button b = sender as Button;
  if (b != null) {
    MessageBox.Show(b.Name);
  }
}
```

then when you create the button, attach the handler:

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Click += btn_Click;
```